# Preg_match_all, conseguir os valores dos atributos name dos inputs

Tags: php, html, regex

Eu estou fazer um projeto com formulários dinâmicos, ou seja, o próprio utilizador (administrador) poderá fazer o seu próprio formulário (HTML/CSS), mas ao ir buscar o formulário à base de dados preciso verificar se os nomes (`name`) dos `inputs` coincidem com os nomes do formulário preenchido pelo utilizador final.

Exemplo de um formulário armazenado na base de dados:

```
name: <input required name="name" type="text"><br>\r\n
nif: <input name="nif" type="text"><br>\r\n
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR YO">
```

Gostaria de ir buscar os valores de todos os atributos `name`, lembrando também (visto não ser previsível) que tanto pode estar armazenado com `""` (`name="email"`) ou com `''` (`name='email'`), o regex deve cobrir os dois casos

Comment: O utilizador escreve o HTML, ou apenas informa o nome dos campos?

Comment: O administrador insere o HTML @PapaCharlie

Comment: Seria algo do tipo, "o html do campo 'name' é :"?, seria sempre em relação a campo ou poderia ter "o html do form"?

Comment: @Miguel Com *regex* eu acho que você pode fazer algo assim: https://regex101.com/r/sA2sM5/1. Por que não usa `Dom`? veja: http://ideone.com/xlrXGt

Comment: Obgado @stderr, acho que devia responder, ambas estão corretas, pode colocar as duas. https://regex101.com/r/sA2sM5/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado em comentário, você pode além de expressões regulares, usar [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) para representar o HTML e obter seus valores.

Supondo que você tenha o seguinte HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto1" value="teste1">
    <input type="hidden" name='produto2' value="teste2">
    <input name="produto3" type="hidden" value="teste3">
    <input type="hidden" name='produto4' value="teste4">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto5" value="teste5">  

<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

### Expressão Regular

Você pode usar a seguinte expressão regular: [`input.*(?<=name=['|"])(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/eJ9nuV/2):

```
preg_match_all('-input.*(?<=name=[\'|"])(\w+)-', $html, $inputs);
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/rQGDmA)</kbd>

Onde:

- `input`: Corresponde literalmente a palavra.
- `.*`: Qualquer caractere, exceto quebra de linha.
- `(?<=name=['|"])(\w+)`: [Lookbehind positivo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Vai corresponder aos caracteres que estiverem no intervalo `a-zA-Z0-9_` somente se forem precedidos por `name=` e `'` ou `"`.

### DOM

Com `DOMDocument` você pode usar [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) para selecionar todos os elementos do HTML ao especificar a tag:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Para retornar os nomes dos elementos selecionados use [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domelement.getattribute.php):

```
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo $input->getAttribute('name') . "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/CvBJWo)</kbd>

Comment: Entretanto consegui dar a volta de outra maneira. Mas é claro que isto responde e bem à pergunta. Obgado